# how can I do it? (3 columns) 1 like

Tags: php, mysql

How can I search in 3 columns with LIKE?

the following code gives an error

```
$sql .= " AND (Genre, Genre2, Genre3) like '%$s2%'";
```

full sql;

```
SELECT * FROM films where Title_ing like '%$s1%' OR Title_de like '%$s1%' AND (Genre like '%$s2%' OR Genre2 '%$s2%' OR Genre3 '%$s2%') AND imdbRating like '$s3%'
```

Comment: you should show your complete query which you have written.

Comment: I think Ravi has posted the answer will help you.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''%Crime%' OR Genre3 '%Crime%') AND imdbRating like '8%' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `OR`

```
AND (Genre like '%$genre%' OR Genre2 '%$genre%' OR Genre3 '%$genre%');
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM films where Title_ing like '%$s1%' OR Title_de like '%$s1%' AND (Genre like '%$s2%' OR Genre2 '%$s2%' OR Genre3 '%$s2%') AND imdbRating like '$s3%' 

I updated my question.

Comment: @defne what error ??

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''%Crime%' OR Genre3 '%Crime%') AND imdbRating like '8%' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: @defne I don't see any issue with update SQL, could you remove LIMIT ??

Comment: problem solved thanks

Comment: @defne happy to hear that

Comment: @Ravi: Shouldn't that be `… OR Genre2 LIKE '%$genre%' OR Genre3 LIKE '%$genre%' …` (2 `LIKE` added)?